# Replace the same values in the consecutive rows and stop replacing once the value has changed in R but conditionally keep values

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements

I had asked a similar question before and indeed solved this issue. see this post:
[Replace the same values in the consecutive rows and stop replacing once the value has changed in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62808087/13578500)

Unfortunately, I realized that I needed an additional conditional statement.

What I wanted before as follows:

- replacing consecutive same values into 0 at the beginning of each trial
- once the value has changed it should stop replacing and keep the value
- it should be repeated in each subject and each trial

For example, first subject has multiple trials (1, 2, etc). At the beginning of each trial, there may be some consecutive rows with the same value (e.g., 1, 1, 1). For these values, I would like to replace them to 0. However, once the value has changed from 1 to 0, I want to keep the values in the rest of the trial (e.g., 0, 0, 1).

```
subject <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) 
trial <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
value <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(subject, trial, value)
```

Thus, from the original data frame, I would like to have a new variable (value_new) like below.

```
   subject trial value value_new
1        1     1     1         0
2        1     1     1         0
3        1     1     1         0
4        1     1     0         0
5        1     1     0         0
6        1     1     1         1
7        1     2     1         0
8        1     2     1         0
9        1     2     0         0
10       1     2     1         1
11       1     2     1         1
12       1     2     1         1
```

**What I want now** is slightly different. Now I have a message column.
I would like to

- replace consecutive same values into 0 after "start"
- once the value has changed it should stop replacing and keep the value
- it should be repeated in each subject and each trial
- importantly, if the value has just changed before "start", I would like to keep all the values after start

```
subject <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) 
trial <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
value <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
message <- c("NA", "start", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "start", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA","NA", "NA", "start", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA")
df <- data.frame(subject, trial, value, message)
df
```

For example, from the original data frame above, I would like to have a new variable (value_new) like below.

```
   subject trial value message new_value
1        1     1     1      NA         1
2        1     1     1   start         0
3        1     1     1      NA         0
4        1     1     1      NA         0
5        1     1     0      NA         0
6        1     1     0      NA         0
7        1     1     1      NA         1
8        1     2     1      NA         1
9        1     2     1   start         0
10       1     2     1      NA         0
11       1     2     0      NA         0
12       1     2     1      NA         1
13       1     2     1      NA         1
14       1     2     1      NA         1
15       1     3     0      NA         0
16       1     3     1   start         1
17       1     3     1      NA         1
18       1     3     1      NA         1
19       1     3     1      NA         1
20       1     3     1      NA         1
21       1     3     0      NA         0
```

I was given a comment which recommended using dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(subject, trial) %>%
  mutate(new_value = value * +(rleid(value) > 1))
```

As a R beginner, I cannot think of how I can tweak it so that it'd work for the new situation.
I was thinking ifelse but still no idea of where and how to put it.

Any suggestions or advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: Should row 7 be 1? Also why the `new_value` doesn't change after "start" in `trial` 3 ?

Comment: My mistake. Yes, the row 7 should be 1. The reason why the new_value doesn't change change after "start" in trial 3 is because the value has just changed at "start" (row 15 = 0, row 17 ("start") = 1). In the other two trials, the value from the previous row was the same the one at "start" and that's why I want to replace those consecutive values after "start" to be 0. If the values between the previous row and the start are different, I want to keep the values after start. Please let me know if it is still confusing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the previous answer to :

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(subject, trial) %>%
  mutate(new_value = value * +(rleid(value) > 1 | 
                               row_number() < match('start', message)))

#   subject trial value message new_value
#1        1     1     1      NA         1
#2        1     1     1   start         0
#3        1     1     1      NA         0
#4        1     1     1      NA         0
#5        1     1     0      NA         0
#6        1     1     0      NA         0
#7        1     1     1      NA         1
#8        1     2     1      NA         1
#9        1     2     1   start         0
#10       1     2     1      NA         0
#11       1     2     0      NA         0
#12       1     2     1      NA         1
#13       1     2     1      NA         1
#14       1     2     1      NA         1
#15       1     3     0      NA         0
#16       1     3     1   start         1
#17       1     3     1      NA         1
#18       1     3     1      NA         1
#19       1     3     1      NA         1
#20       1     3     1      NA         1
#21       1     3     0      NA         0
```

Here we add an additional condition to keep the rows before `'start'` to be the same as `value`.

Comment: I'm sorry for this delayed comment. I haven't had a change to look at this dataset for a while and get back to it. I really appreciate your help!